# Intel gigabit ethernet teaming - Which option should I pick, and how do I get it working?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have an intel 82579V gigabit ethernet adaptor built into my motherboard, and it supports 'teaming' - a feature that lets me use more than one ethernet adaptor together. I'm not entirely sure if its a function of the specific driver, windows 8 or both, but it seems neat.

I have a second, realtek PCI gig-e card from my spares bin that's apparently supported, and I'm trying to understand which option does what. The system is connected to a unmanaged 'dumb' cisco linksys e2500

[image]

As I understand it, AFT and ALB would work on any switch - with AFT switching over if one link dies, and AFT increasing downstream speeds, Dynamic Link aggregation would work with a switch that supports IEEE802.3ad (which mine dosen't), and switch fault tolerance would work if I was on different switches. "Static Link Aggregation" needs some undefined configuration switch side, and both aggregation options *should* improve speeds. But what do they *really* do?

I've tried the two obvious options - AFT and ALB, and both don't seem to work, the TEAM device created is disabled and I can't enable it. I often have to reboot to get wired network connectivity back when I try this too. The test switch option is also greyed out, so I'm guessing its a problem with the setup.

How do I determine which option to pick, and what's the *practical* difference between them? What do I need to look at on my switch and nic specifications when trying to pick which option to use?

Answer (score 0):

In general NIC Teaming under Windows from manufacturer drivers requires compatible hardware. In practice this is generally two (or more) identical NICs. [Intel seems to be preferred and Realtek looked down upon](https://dfarq.homeip.net/intel-nic-vs-realtek/).

However, NIC teaming is **not supported** in any current (July 2018) *client* version of windows (cf. [Is Windows 10 Software NIC Teaming now possible?](https://superuser.com/questions/955825/is-windows-10-software-nic-teaming-now-possible?rq=1))

NIC teaming *is* supported in Windows Server OSes from 2012-on via the OS itself... and teaming in many different and flexible configurations is available in most flavors of Linux (cf. https://www.tecmint.com/network-nic-bonding-teaming-in-debian-linux/)

Basically your first step needs to be to install an OS that supports teaming properly and move on from there.